# Не могу "выйти" из программы

Tags: linux, debian, ввод

"Загнал" программу чтоб запускалась при запуске bash-a, но случилась "оказия"

**Cntrl**+**Z** Не выводит программу из "работы " 0_0 *к такому меня жизнь не готовила*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй нажать `Ctrl+C`, либо через `kill` в терминале

Comment: `Ctrl+C` **сработало** :3, `kill`  даже не пробовал.